# Как распарсить json в go?

Tags: json, golang

Как распарсить json в go? Есть следующий код:

```
type testRecord struct {
  To_socket []string `json:"to_socket"`
  Message []string `json:"message"`
}

var ans testRecord
b := []byte(`{"to_socket":"11","message":"message_texttt"}`)   //Это я получаю с клиента
err = json.Unmarshal(b, &ans)
// log.Printf("%#v", ans)
// log.Printf("Значение To_socket=" +ans.To_socket)  // здесь я хочу получить значение
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас в структуре testRecord поля описаны как массив строк []string, а в json вы их передаёте как строку string.
Исправьте это, так примерно:

```
type testRecord struct {
    To_socket string `json:"to_socket"`
    Message string `json:"message"`
}
```

В остальном вроде всё верно.

Answer (score 0):

> type testRecord struct {
>               To_socket string `json:"to_socket"`
>               Message string `json:"message"`           }
>
> ```
>         var ans testRecord
>           b := []byte(`{"to_socket":"11","message":"message_texttt"}`)
>         err := json.Unmarshal(b, &ans)
>         log.Printf("Значение To_socket=" +ans.To_socket)
> ```